# CSS - How to target Second Child List Items?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am having trouble targeting the `<li>` of a `<ul>` that is a child of another `<li>` using a CSS child combinator selector - `>`.

I am needing to add a `list_style_type:SomethingElse` to only those list items and `list-style-type: none;` for all others.

I am already using the following to remove the list style:

```
.snap-drawer ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

And the following does'nt chang anything:

```
.snap-drawer ul > li {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="snap-drawer">
    <ul>
        <li class="li-item">...</li>
        <li class="li-item">...</li>
        <li class="li-item">
            <ul>
                <li class="li-item">...</li> <==== Target all these only
                <li class="li-item">...</li> <==== Target all these only
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course `.snap-drawer ul > li` doesn’t work, because that matches the `li` on the first _and_ second level, since both are children of a `ul` inside `.snap-drawer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is this:

```
.snap-drawer ul ul > li {
    list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

Or more simply:

```
.snap-drawer ul ul li {
    list-style-type: disc;
}
```

Comment: Or more simply: `.snap-drawer li li {`

Comment: I had tried that too but nadda ...but, I just discovered it was the `.snap-drawer ul {padding: 0;...} causing the issue buy forcing the elements off view.  Your answer is technically correct.  Thnx!

Answer (score 3):

#### Option1

You are removing the `padding` then the `bullet` isn't visible.

Also target the `ul` inside `li` item. Try:

```
.snap-drawer ul > li > ul {
    padding-left:25px;
    list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

```css
.snap-drawer ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.snap-drawer ul > li > ul {
  padding-left: 25px;
  list-style-type: disc !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="snap-drawer">
    <ul>
        <li class="li-item">...</li>
        <li class="li-item">...</li>
        <li class="li-item">
            <ul>
                <li class="li-item">...</li> <==== Target all these only
                <li class="li-item">...</li> <==== Target all these only
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

#### Option2

You can try the `>` selector just for the first `ul` too:

```
.snap-drawer > ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```css
.snap-drawer > ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="snap-drawer">
    <ul>
        <li class="li-item">...</li>
        <li class="li-item">...</li>
        <li class="li-item">
            <ul>
                <li class="li-item">...</li> <==== Target all these only
                <li class="li-item">...</li> <==== Target all these only
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```